# Link an in-app purchase to user apple account

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I'm looking for a way to link an in-app purchase (non-renewable subscription) to the user apple account, because my app doesn't have account system, and obviously I want the user to keep his subscription.

I read that we can't get the Apple ID, but I think there is a way to do it because most of iOS apps can save datas with your Apple account.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: what do you mean link in-app? you just linked with your apple iTunes connect account with current app identifier.

Comment: I already created in-app purchases in itunes connect, I mean save purchases when user buy an object.

Comment: Are you asking about restoring purchases?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have your own account system (where the user can login etc), you can check the user's purchases for your app from the purchase receipt:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html

Getting personal information like AppleID etc is not possible from the SDK.

Comment: It seems to be very difficult with encryption, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You should keep track of already purchased products in your app yourself. I usually use `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:productIdentifier]` for this.

The problem arises when your users reinstalls your app or buys a new device. In this case you must implement a way to restore the purchased products.

The [In-App Purchase Programmering Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html) states that one way to implement this is by calling `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]`. This sends a request to the App Store to restore all of your app’s completed transactions.

Then `paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions` of your transaction observer will be called and `transactions` holds the restored products. My function usually looks something like this:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
}`
```

Complete the restoration process (providing content, update `NSUserDefaults` etc.) in `restoreTransaction`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem is that I want to know if the user already bought products without going in the in-app view controller

Comment: The code for checking if the product is already bought or not shouldn't have anything to do with the view controller. It may be located in the view controller but most developers agree that it's good practice to separate the code that present the view from the business logic. That said, the code in the answer could/should be in its own class (together with the rest of the in-app purchase logic) and you should be able to use its features from anywhere in your code. Even before going into the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

For non-renewal subscription you have to manually store the expiry date somewhere because Apple does not manages it for non-renewal.

I had implemented this feature in one of my application where after subscription I used to store the expire date on server and app will check for expire date while accessing paid features.

If found expired, app will ask to purchase subscription again.

Reference link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH3-SW1

https://www.progressconcepts.com/blog/non-renewing-subscription-app-purchases-ios/

Hope this helps.